# Product of semialgebraic sets is semialgebraic

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove that the product of semialgebraic sets is semialgebraic.

If $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are semialgebraic, I can't see the polynomial conditions involved on the representation of $X \times Y$. My first idea was taking the product of the polynomials $P_{i,j} s_{i,j} 0$ of X and $Q_{i,j} s'_{i,j} 0$ of Y, but it doesn't seem to make sense. I have no clue of how it goes, and I have only the definition and the characterization of semialgebraic sets as the minimal collection of sets that contains $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : P(x) > 0 \}$ where $P$ is a polynomial  and is closed under finite intersections, unions and complements.

Comment: Do you know some foundations of measure theory (the parts where you really care about what your $\sigma$-algebras are)? It’s a similar mode of reasoning that works here. The idea is to consider some collections stable under intersection/union/complements and containing your $\{P >0\}$ – therefore they will contain semi-algebraic sets.

Comment: When you say you "can't see the polynomial conditions involved [in] the representation of $X\times Y$", what do you mean?  Remember, a point in $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m$ is in $X\times Y$ iff its coordinate in $\Bbb R^n$ is in $X$ and its coordinate in $\Bbb R^m$ is in $Y$.

Comment: @KReiser I mean that I am not being able to understand what should be the polynomials in n+m variables that should be in the representation of the product of X and Y. My first thought was the one described, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your description from your post - it looks like you maybe had a typographical issue? But it is absolutely true that if $X$ is described by the conditions $p_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $Y$ is described by the conditions $q_j(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$, then $X\times Y$ is described by the conditions $p_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $q_j(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$. Perhaps you could expand upon your difficulties with an [edit]?

Comment: @KReiser, indeed it is, but I can't see why this gives the structure of a semialgebraic set. Because I still don't see what are the polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[X_{1},...,X_{n}]$ and signs that give $X \times Y$ the structure of a semialgebraic set. I've seen that explanation you gave before, but it is not clear to me why this works.

Comment: Like I just told you, they're exactly the conditions on $X$ for the first $n$ variables and the conditions on $Y$ for the last $m$ variables. Unless/until you explain what your difficulties are with an [edit], I'm not sure I have anything more to say here. Maybe you should try a few examples.

Answer (score -1):

A semi-algebraic set is not necessary described by polynomials, but it's boolean combination of sets described by polynomials ( equalities and inequalities )
( see http://gcomte.perso.math.cnrs.fr/M2/CosteIntroToSemialGeo.pdf ).

Take $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ semi-algebraic, you want to prove that $X\times Y$ is semi-algebraic. You can go stup by stup:

**Stup1:** it's enough to assume that $X=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; P(x)=0 \; and \; P_1(x)>0 \; and \; ...\; and \; P_l(x)>0   \}$ and $Y=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^m \; : \; Q(y)=0 \; and \; Q_1(y)>0 \; and \; ...\; and \; Q_p(y)>0   \}$, where $P,P_1 ,..., P_l \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $Q,Q_1 ,..., Q_p \in \mathbb{R}[y]$.
( you can using properties of the Cartesian product).

**Stup2:** Note that if $f:\mathbb{R}^k \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a semi-algebraic map ( means that the graph of $f$ is a semi-algebraic set ), then the sets $\{z \; : \; f(z)=0  \}$, $\{z \; : \; f(z)>0  \}$, and $\{z \; : \; f(z)<0  \}$ are semi-algebraic.

**Stup3:** the map $\mid \;  \mid :\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto \mid x \mid$ is semi-algebraic ( easy to show ), and therefore any set described by composition of semi-algebraic maps with $\mid \; \mid$ is semi-algebraic.

**Stup4:** the $Min$ map is semi-algebraic, indeed:

$Min(z,w)=\frac{z+w- \mid z-w \mid}{2}$.

**Stup5:** $X\times Y$ can be described by semi-algebraic functions as the following:

$X\times Y= \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \; : \; P^2 (x)+Q^2 (y)=0 \; and \; Min(P_1 (x),...,P_l (x),Q_1 (y),...,Q_p (y))>0     \}$.

Hence, $X\times Y$ is a semi-algebraic set.